# How to convert this query from sql to linq-to-entities

Tags: linq, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to convert following query from sql(Oracle) to linq-to-entities:

```
select * FROM ActivityPromptText where ActivityId = 8 
         and ProcessTypeId = 1 and ProcessId is null
```

When I am writing this c#, its returning `null`, while same query is returning result in sql.
The Linq query is:

```
var text2 = this.context.ActivityPromptText
       .Where(pt => (pt.ActivityId == activityId && pt.ProcessTypeId == processType) 
                      && pt.ProcessId == null)
      .Include(pt => pt.Prompt).FirstOrDefault();
```

=======================

The MODELS are:

```
[Table("ActivityPromptText")]
public class ActivityPromptText
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PromptTextId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int ProcessTypeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public int? ProcessId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PromptTextId")]
    public virtual PromptText MbopPrompt { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
[Table("PromptText")]
public class PromptText
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PromptTextId { get; set; }

    public string PromptText { get; set; }
```

## }

and  The DBContext file has:

public virtual DbSet ActivityPromptTexts { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet PromptTexts { get; set; }

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried this: var text2 = this.context.ActivityPromptText .Where(pt => pt.ActivityId == activityId && pt.ProcessTypeId == processType && pt.ProcessId == null) .Include(pt => pt.Prompt).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Okay why you have parenthesis in Where clause? Between `ProcessTypeId ` & `ProcessId ` ? It change the query right? Change it like this and try:- `.Where(pt => pt.ActivityId == activityId && pt.ProcessTypeId == processType  && pt.ProcessId == null)`

Comment: @RahulSingh the parenthesis doesn't do anything. I think the problem lies somewhere within his model as the query looks correct. Can you show your models for `Prompt` and `ActivityPromptText`?

Comment: public virtual DbSet<ActivityPromptText> ActivityPromptTexts { get; set; } and 
        public virtual DbSet<PromptText> PromptTexts { get; set; }

Comment: @AlexanderDerck - Yes you are correct, it won't make difference in this context.

Comment: @shivani please edit your original post

Comment: The line "&& pt.ProcessId == null" is giving issues - if I pass any ID here, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `Key` attribute for your `ProcessId` property. Keys can't be null i think, are they really keys or rather indexes? If they're indexes and you're using EF6.1+ : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index

Multi-column indexes are also supported.

Comment: You're welcome, just out of curiosity, did Entity framework generate this code? I once had it too that EF used the key attribute instead of index

Comment: No, we're using EF code first. We create entities for the tables in database.